# Using a script multiple times on different directories

Tags: shell, command

I've written a shell script that functions on a .dcm files and organizes them by certain parameters of the image. I need my program to act on many directories of files but only the files in a single directory at a time. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a variable array with all your directories and then have a for loop execute the commands on each of them?  Ensure that you use the full path to each directory in the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#
DIR1="/tmp/testdir1/"
DIR2="/tmp/testdir1/nestdir1/"
DIR3="/tmp/testdir2/"
DIR4="/tmp/testdir2/nestdir2/"
DIR5="/tmp/testdir3/"
DIR6="/tmp/testdir3/nestdir3/"
declare -a DIRECTORIES=("$DIR1" "$DIR2" "$DIR3" "$DIR4" "$DIR5" "$DIR6")
for DIR in "${DIRECTORIES[@]}"; do
    cd "$DIR"
    touch testfile
done
```